# Jenkinsfile - Trigger different branches with different parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a job that I wand to start every 10 minutes with a specific parameter on a specific branch.

I use this code to set a parameter and launch the job every 10 minutes:

```java
properties([
  parameters([
      string(defaultValue: 'regularPipeline', description: 'A parameter to run the health monitoring', name: 'Health')
  ]),
  pipelineTriggers([
    [
      $class: 'hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger',
      spec: "H/10 * * * *"
    ]
  ])
])
```

How can I make the TimerTrigger to receive a param. And how can I run this job only on a specific brach?

Comment: I think the last part doesn't make sense. The `properties` only affect the _next_ run of the job IIRC - except you really use this `Jenkinsfile` in multiple branches and only want that the job is triggered for this branch every 10min.

Comment: Try to be a bit more explicit, why you want these conditions. The defaults for the parameters should be used (and can be accessed inside the job via `params`), when the job is triggered.

Comment: @StephenKing I use this Jenkinsfile in multiple branches and I want to trigger a build every 10 minutes in a specific branch with a specific param. I'll update the question. Thanks!

Comment: Which job type? Multibranch (or it's children Github org etc) I guess? Then you have a job per branch and this should trigger itself, right? Have you tried above config? What's the result?

Comment: @StephenKing I'm quite new to this so bear with me... What do you mean by job type?
This code is inside the project repo. So every branch I will upload this to will launch every 10 minutes. I want to trigger it only on the master branch, so that the develop branch (for example) will ignore this trigger.

Comment: The job types, which automatically add branches containing a `Jenkinsfile` are _Pipeline_, _Multibranch Pipeline_, _(GitHub|Bitbucket) Organization_. But it seems you have one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following pseudo-code (probably contains syntax errors) should help:

```java
def triggers = [] 
if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
  triggers << [
    $class: 'hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger',
    spec: "H/10 * * * *"
  ]
}
properties([
  parameters([
    string(defaultValue: 'regularPipeline', description: 'A parameter to run the health monitoring', name: 'Health')
  ]),
  pipelineTriggers(triggers)
])
```

In case of non-master branch, you will set no triggers. For the master branch, you will apply the above-defined `TimerTrigger`.

Comment: Sure, then just set another default for the _master_ branch. Extract the `defaultValue` into a variable just as the triggers..

Comment: @StephanKing This works. I also need to launch the timed job with param 'Health' which is not the default param. Is this possible?

Comment: or a parameter called `Health`.. as you like.

Comment: OK got it! Thanks!